# How can I get the pages that a Facebook account has with SDK 5.0?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

From here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/ I got to write this in my code

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
             $session,
             'GET',
             '/{user-id}/accounts'
           );

$response = $request->execute();
```

The problem here is with version 2.8 of the API and SDK 5.0 execute() doesn't exist. How can I get a list of all the pages on a Facebook account.

Comment: Go check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted, it has basic examples written for the PHP SDK v5. (You won’t find an exact example for this - but that doesn’t matter, it is just a basic API request, and how to make those can been gathered from the examples.)

Comment: I've seen those. Their examples for getting the pages a Facebook user administers doesn't work for me.

Comment: Again: It is a very basic API request. So even a trivial example as the one titled _Retrieve User Profile_ can be adapted to request the list of pages instead in no time.

Comment: I get that it's basic. I've tried many ways, guess what I need is a function that returns the page IDs in an array or something. Because what it return is an Object of Object of... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JayNCoke was correct with the approach.

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

// Sets the default fallback access token so we don't have to pass it to each request
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken('{access-token}');

$response = $fb->get('{user-id}/accounts');
```

$response returns a Facebook\FacebookResponse object

To get it in a usable data format, just call getDecodedBody() like below

```
$response = $response->getDecodedBody();
```

This returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right endpoint, you just need to make sure you have the right call in PHP:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

// Sets the default fallback access token so we don't have to pass it to each request
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken('{access-token}');

$response = $fb->get('{user-id}/accounts');
```

Also remember:

- You'll need to make sure your app is asking for the `manage_pages` permission.
- This only returns pages that the user is an Admin on. If they are of any other role, it won't return that page.

Comment: I appreciate. This works $response in this case returns Facebook\FacebookResponse object which is hard to get the needed data out of, what I really need is something that returns the pages in an array or something smoother.